# How to temporarily disable JVM JIT stalls during runtime

Tags: java, jvm, jit

I have a server latency-sensitive application. 
My main worker loops, which usually completes in under 1ms, is sometimes delayed for up to 10ms (i.e. x10 latency).

These delays may occur once every few hrs, and seem to correlate with some JIT re-optimization.

Is there a reliable way to temporarily disable the JIT?

Is the compiler.disable() class supported and reliable ?! 
Can it be toggled on/off with msec precision (i.e. every time i enter a latency- sensitive function)

I am currently using the Oracle server 64 bit JVM, and trying the Azul JVM. Also, i have resolved other causes such as GC, cache, i/o, sleeps, context switches, etc.

Comment: Why do you think the delays are related to JIT? Use `-XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics -XX:PrintSafepointStatisticsCount=1` to find the reason of pauses.

Comment: `Compiler.disable` is no-op in Oracle JDK, and there is no supported way to temporarily disable JIT compilation.

Comment: “re-optimization”? If there is an event causing it, you obviously can’t disable the associated de-optimization. Turning off the JIT in that situation would imply running in the even slower interpreted mode afterwards.